# función binario a decimal en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema en resolver el siguiente ejercicio en el cual tengo que pasar un número binario a número decimal.

Empecé por los arrays ya que se me hizo lo más apropiado, en *positions1* guarde el índice invertido, usé un bucle `for` para elevar `2 ** [i]`. Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora tengo que multiplicar los resultados por cada número binario respetando el índice, o sea `rspPotencia[0] * num[0]` y así sucesivamente.

Traté de hacerlo con un bucle anidado pero obviamente no es la solución. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar en este penúltimo paso? Ya que cuando lo resuelva solo me queda sumar todos los números del array y así obtener el número entero(Decimal):

```
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  // tu codigo aca
  let acc = 0;
  let rspPotencia = [];
  let positions = num.split('');
  let positions1 = [];
  let potxbinario = [];

  positions.forEach(function (element, index) {
    positions1.push(index);
  });
  let ps2 = positions1.reverse();
  for (var i = 0; i < ps2.length; i++) {
    rspPotencia.push(2 ** ps2[i]);
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < rspPotencia.length; j++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < num.length; l) {
      potxbinario.push(rspPotencia[i] * num[i]);
    }
  }

  return potxbinario;
}
```

Comment: tienes un error en el push, me imagino que sería `push(rspPotencia[i] * num[i])`

Comment: Supongo que no puedes hacerlo con métodos nativos de JS, cierto? Por ejemplo: `parseInt('101', 2)` Devuelve 5.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev atención con las ediciones de código: estás agregando `;` extra... Recordá no alterar el código, solo remover los espacios innecesarios.

Comment: @padaleiana lo siento, mi editor de código lo formatea automáticamente así =/, y no creo que esto genere conflicto o cambios drásticos en el código.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev de hecho, al parecer el código original tiene un _typo_ (en el último `push`).

Comment: @padaleiana Ok, seré más cuidadoso con eso =).

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un snippet corto que quizas te ayude, no es necesario hacer tantos bucles, te puede dar una idea de como aplicarlo por vos mismo:

```
function fromBinary(binary){
  let pows = [] // array de potencias ordenadas de mayor a menor
  let result = 0; // resultado
  for(let i=binary.length-1; i>=0; i--) pows.push(2 ** i); 
  // llenamos pows con las potencias de 2 usando un for invertido
  for(let i=0; i<binary.length; i++) if(binary[i]==1) result += pows[i]; // 
  // recorremos el binario caracter por caracter. Si es un 1 se le suma a result la potencia de 2 ubicada en pow en el mismo indice del caracter comparado
  // pow y binary tienen por definicion tamaños iguales
  return result; // devolvemos
}

console.log(fromBinary("1101110001"))
```

De todas maneras supongo que es un ejercicio, en el día a día si necesitas convertir un binario a decimal fácil y rápido simplemente haces:

```
Number.parseInt("010001110",2); // (numero, base numerica)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sin arreglos y mucho más sencillo, vendría suficiente hacer la operación con el parámetro que recibas y solo con un **`for`**, sería lo siguiente:

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  let acc = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    acc = acc + (num[i] * 2 ** i) / 2;
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(BinarioADecimal('0110')); // 3
console.log(BinarioADecimal('010101')); // 21
console.log(BinarioADecimal('010110101')); // 173
```